# google chrome font unreadable

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

Specifically for font in family "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif Google Chrome renders my pages almost unreadable. Does anyone know how to fix this?

e.g. from https://docs.angularjs.org/api

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed all versions of the Helvetica Neue font on Windows. While removing it, even though Windows mentions multiple fonts, it seemed to resurfice a few times.